# mysql ERROR 2003 [HY000] - When i'm trying to connect to remote mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, remote-access, shared-hosting

I have mysql database in shared hosting that defined with `%` in "remote MySQL" in a **Cpanel**

And I type within CMD:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u SiteName_username -p pass_of_mysql -h srv3.linuxisrael.co.il
```

I press ENTER

```
Enter password :
```

I press ENTER

> P.S - It's right to press here ENTER ?
>
> I do not have a password in MySQL installed on my computer

And i get :

`mysql error 2003 (hy000) Can't connect to MySQl server on 'srv3.linuxisrael.co.il' (10060 "Unknown error")`

---

And in Laravel 5.1 i get this error:

> **PDOException in** Connector.php line 55:
>
> **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond.**

it's configured so :

env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY= ...........

DB_HOST=srv3.linuxisrael.co.il
DB_DATABASE= name_of_my_database
DB_USERNAME=name_of_database_username
DB_PASSWORD=password_of_the_username

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Routes.php :

```
use App\User;

Route::get('/', function(){
    User::create(['first_name' => 'moti']);
    return view('welcome');
});
```

How can I connect to MySQL?

I want to connect through Laravel
But I see that it does not work for me even when I try via the **CMD**

What's the solution?

**thank you very much !**

Comment: It looks like there may be a firewall blocking MySQL connections to the hosting server.

Comment: I do not think so. They told me there was no problem to connect remotely
Customer Service

Comment: What do you see if you do `telnet srv3.linuxisrael.co.il 3306` ?

Comment: I do not have

What do I need to install to test it? I'll check

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows comes with a `telnet` command.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked using following command through CMD:

```
telnet srv3.linuxisrael.co.il 3306
```

It is not able to connect through port 3306. So it seems there is some issue with the server side and port 3306 is not opened to the world.

You can check the mysql connection using following simple PHP code snippet.

```
$conn = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks. but i get this error `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Comment: You are welcome :). Yes, I checked again and it seems that the port 3306 is still not opened from the server side. Please contact your hosting provider with the sample PHP script I provided. So that they can open the port and check the output.